# What does CircleCI do with non-0 exit codes?

Tags: shell, continuous-integration, exit-code, circleci

This seems very basic but I can't find it anywhere in the docs. I'm working on a project where we run some tests through a shell script wrapper like:

```
./foo.sh a 
./foo.sh b
./foo.sh c
```

`foo.sh` does not output XUnit format, so we need a different way to signal failure to CircleCI. Is `exit 1` (or any nonzero exit code) recognized as a failure? What conditions cause CircleCI to report a step as having failed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, CircleCI fails the build if any command, whether it runs tests or not, exits with a non-zero exit code. Documented in the [configuration reference](https://circleci.com/docs/configuration-reference/#default-shell-options).

These snippets pulled from the above link go into detail on why that's the case:

> For jobs that run on Linux, the default value of the shell option is
> /bin/bash -eo pipefail

> Descriptions of the -eo pipefail options
> are provided below.
>
> `-e`
>
> Exit immediately if a pipeline (which may consist of a single simple
> command), a subshell command enclosed in parentheses, or one of the
> commands executed as part of a command list enclosed by braces exits
> with a non-zero status.

> -o pipefail
>
> If pipefail is enabled, the pipeline’s return status is the value of
> the last (rightmost) command to exit with a non-zero status, or zero
> if all commands exit successfully. The shell waits for all commands in
> the pipeline to terminate before returning a value.